# Intersection of a Line and Surface Point Cloud

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-geometry, data-analysis

I am trying to determine where a given straight line intersects a small cluster of points that define an arbitrary surface in 3-D space. My approach has been to create a surface defined as

$z = a + bx + cy + dxy + ex^2 + fy^2$

where $(x,y,z)$ are the known points defining the surface. Once I have all of the coefficients, I substitute the symmetric form of the straight line into my regression and get a quadratic equation for $z$.

My issue now is that I will obtain two solutions that satisfy both the straight line and surface equations, but I only want to keep the one that lies on the portion of the surface provided by my initial small cluster of points. My original thought was to compute the convex hull of the point cloud and then check the distances between both solutions and each triangle defining the convex hull, but this is more computationally expensive than I would like. Is there a faster or possibly different approach to eliminating the solution I don't want?

Comment: Your surface is a quadric surface. Have you checked the values of the coefficients to see what kind of quadric surface you're obtaining?

Comment: Yes I have looked at the coefficients and even plotted the surface. Seems that depending on the orientation between the line and surface, I will get either 1 or 2 intersections

Comment: How many points are in your cluster, typically? My thought is to compute the $z$ coordinate of the center-of-mass of your cluster, and see which solution of the quadratic is closer to that.

Comment: Typically its around 25 points. And choosing the incorrect point causes issues so I want to make sure that it will choose the correct one even if the surface has a large bend to it

Comment: Do you think my solution is too simple to work? A visualization would help to see what's going on.

Comment: I was concerned that large spacing between points or an increased number of points might make it so that the incorrect intersection was selected, but so far your suggestion has worked for all of my test cases!

Comment: Well, I've worked in data science long enough to know that's no guarantee, but cautious optimism might be justified. Keep in touch!